# D3 chart inside a div in angular2 applicaiton not rendering properly

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am new to d3.
I am integrating d3 chart in my angular2 application. This is customized d3 chart. The chart is not rendering completely and it works only when i press F12 key. Is there any reason why is this happening? in the below code snippet, relationship-chart is the d3 chart.

```
<div class="ui-g" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <relationship-chart></relationship-chart>                      
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Here is the relationshipchart d3 code:

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'trader-relationship-chart',
  template: `
    <div (window:resize)='onResize($event)'>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./trader-relationship-chart.component.scss']
})
export class TraderRelationshipChartComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() trader;
  @Input() relationships;

  private DOM;
  private HOST;
  private SVG;

  private width;
  private height;

  private config = {
    chartHeight: 450,
    chartWidth: 0,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    topPadding: 5,
    mainTraderLeftPos: 60,
    mainTraderTopPos: 60,
    mainTraderRadius: 60,
    chartLeft: 90
  };

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    this.DOM = this.element.nativeElement;
    console.log(this.DOM);
    this.HOST = d3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.redraw();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.redraw();
  }

  redraw(): void {
    this.dimensions();
    this.defs();
    this.networkChart();
    this.traderDetails();

    this.selectedtrader(
      {
        traderName: 'Trader name',
        traderInitials: 'TN',
        riskScore: 56,
        trades: 'Multi Currency',
        desk: 'FX - EM Spot',
        location: 'Boston',
        manager: 'Tony Bloar',
        emailsIn: 34,
        emailsOut: 23,
        im: 77,
        phone: 2
      },
      0
    );
  }

  dimensions(): void {
    this.width = this.DOM.clientWidth;
    this.height = this.config.chartHeight;

    this.config.chartWidth =
      this.width - this.config.marginLeft - this.config.marginRight;
  }

  defs(): void {
    this.HOST
      .style('height', this.height + 'px')
      .style('background-color', '#333333')
      .html('');
    this.SVG = this.HOST
      .append('svg')
      .style('width', '100%')
      .style('height', this.height + 'px')
      .attr('fill', '#333333')
      .on('click', this.backgroundClicked);

    let filter = this.SVG
      .append('defs')
      .append('filter')
      .attr('id', 'drop-shadow')
      .attr('x', -1)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', '200%')
      .attr('height', '200%');
    filter
      .append('feOffset')
      .attr('result', 'offOut')
      .attr('in', 'SourceAlpha')
      .attr('dx', -1)
      .attr('dy', 0);
    filter
      .append('feGaussianBlur')
      .attr('result', 'blurOut')
      .attr('in', 'offOut')
      .attr('stdDeviation', 1);
    filter
      .append('feBlend')
      .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
      .attr('in2', 'blurOut')
      .attr('mode', 'normal');

    let svgDefs = this.SVG.append('defs');

    let mainGradient = svgDefs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'mainGradient')
      .attr('x1', '40%')
      .attr('x2', '80%')
      .attr('y1', '0%')
      .attr('y2', '100%');

    mainGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#c2b00f')
      .attr('offset', '0%')
      .attr('stop-opacity', 0.4);

    mainGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#ffe600')
      .attr('offset', '100%')
      .attr('stop-opacity', 0.8);
  }

  radians = function (degree) {
    return degree * Math.PI / 180;
  };

  networkChart(): void {
    let cx = 60;
    let cy = 60;
    let r = 60;
    let major_axis = this.config.chartWidth / 1.2;
    let minor_axis = this.config.chartHeight / 1.2;

    this.SVG
      .selectAll('.relLine')
      .data(this.relationships)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('class', 'relLine')
      .attr(
      'x1',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.cos(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * major_axis + cx
      )
      .attr(
      'y1',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.sin(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * minor_axis + cy
      )
      .attr('x2', cx + r)
      .attr('y2', cy + r)
      .attr('stroke', 'url(#mainGradient)')
      .attr(
      'stroke-width',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        20 * ((this.relationships.length - i) / this.relationships.length)
      )
      .attr('fill', 'url(#mainGradient)');

    let traderContainer = this.SVG
      .append('g')
      .attr(
      'transform',
      'translate(' +
      this.config.mainTraderLeftPos +
      ',' +
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos +
      ')'
      );

    traderContainer
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', cx)
      .attr('cy', cy)
      .attr('r', this.config.mainTraderRadius)
      .attr('filter', 'url(#drop-shadow)')
      .attr('fill', '#ffe600');

    let textContainer = traderContainer
      .append('text')
      .style('fill', '#333333')
      .style('font-size', '45')
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .text(this.trader.traderInitials);
    let textWidth = textContainer.node().getBBox().width;
    let textHeight = textContainer.node().getBBox().height;

    textContainer
      .attr('dx', 60 - textWidth / 2)
      .attr('dy', textHeight + textHeight / 3);

    this.SVG
      .selectAll('.relCircles')
      .data(this.relationships)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'relCircles')
      .attr('id', (d, i) => 'relCircles' + i)
      .attr(
      'cx',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.cos(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * major_axis + cx
      )
      .attr(
      'cy',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.sin(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * minor_axis + cy
      )
      .attr(
      'r',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        50 * ((this.relationships.length + 1 - i) / this.relationships.length)
      )
      .attr('stroke', '#58595b')
      .attr('fill', '#58595b');

    this.SVG
      .selectAll('.relText')
      .data(this.relationships)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'relText')
      .attr(
      'x',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.cos(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * major_axis + cx
      )
      .attr(
      'y',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.sin(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * minor_axis +
        cy +
        50 *
        ((this.relationships.length + 1 - i) / this.relationships.length) /
        3
      )
      .style('fill', '#333333')
      .style(
      'font-size',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        50 * ((this.relationships.length + 1 - i) / this.relationships.length)
      )
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text((d: any, i: any) => d.traderInitials);

    this.SVG
      .selectAll('.relCirclesLayer')
      .data(this.relationships)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'relCirclesLayer')
      .attr('id', (d, i) => 'relCirclesLayer' + i)
      .attr(
      'cx',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.cos(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * major_axis + cx
      )
      .attr(
      'cy',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        Math.sin(this.radians(55 - i * 10)) * minor_axis + cy
      )
      .attr(
      'r',
      (d: any, i: any) =>
        50 * ((this.relationships.length + 1 - i) / this.relationships.length)
      )
      .attr('fill', '#ffffff')
      .attr('opacity', '0')
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .on('click', this.selectedtrader);
  }

  traderDetails(): void {
    let detailsContainer = this.SVG
      .append('g')
      .attr('id', 'detailsGroup')
      .style('display', 'none');

    let traderNameText = detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr('id', 'traderName')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3
      )
      .style('fill', '#4eecf6')
      .style('font-size', 20)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .text('Damein Go0dard');

    let textWidth = traderNameText.node().getBBox().width;
    let textHeight = traderNameText.node().getBBox().height;

    detailsContainer
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', textWidth + 30)
      .attr(
      'cy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 - 7
      )
      .attr('r', 20)
      .attr('stroke', '#4eecf6')
      .attr('fill', '#4eecf6');

    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr('id', 'riskScore')
      .attr('x', textWidth + 30)
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3
      )
      .style('fill', '#333333')
      .style('font-size', 20)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text('86');

    //Trades

    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 + 50
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .append('tspan')
      .text('Trades:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'trades')
      .attr('x', 70)
      .text('N/A');

    //Desk
    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 + 70
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .append('tspan')
      .text('Desk:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'desk')
      .attr('x', 70)
      .text('Research');

    //Location
    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 + 90
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .append('tspan')
      .text('Loc:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'location')
      .attr('x', 70)
      .text('Canary Wharf');

    //Manager
    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 +
      this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 +
      110
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .append('tspan')
      .text('Manager:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'manager')
      .attr('x', 70)
      .text('Stuart Benjamin');

    //EmailsIn
    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 + 50
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .attr('x', 220)
      .append('tspan')
      .text('Emails In:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'emailsIn')
      .attr('x', 310)
      .text('4');

    //EmailsOut
    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 + 70
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .attr('x', 220)
      .append('tspan')
      .text('Emails Out:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'emailsOut')
      .attr('x', 310)
      .text('5');

    //IM
    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 + this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 + 90
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .attr('x', 220)
      .append('tspan')
      .text('IM:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'im')
      .attr('x', 310)
      .text('1');

    //Phone
    detailsContainer
      .append('text')
      .attr(
      'dy',
      this.config.mainTraderTopPos * 2 +
      this.config.mainTraderRadius * 3 +
      110
      )
      .style('fill', '#e0e0e0')
      .style('font-size', 14)
      .style('font-weight', 'lighter')
      .style('text-anchor', 'left')
      .attr('x', 220)
      .append('tspan')
      .text('Phone:')
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('id', 'phone')
      .attr('x', 310)
      .text('0');

    detailsContainer.attr(
      'transform',
      'translate(' + this.config.marginLeft * 2 + ',20)'
    );
  }

  selectedtrader(d, i): void {
    console.log(`Selected Trader d:${d} i:%{i}`);
    d3.selectAll('.relCircles').attr('fill', '#58595b');

    d3.select('#relCircles' + i).attr('fill', '#4eecf6');

    d3.select('#detailsGroup').style('display', 'block');

    d3.select('#traderName').text(d.traderName);
    d3.select('#riskScore').text(d.riskScore);
    d3.select('#trades').text(d.trades);
    d3.select('#desk').text(d.desk);
    d3.select('#location').text(d.location);
    d3.select('#manager').text(d.manager);
    d3.select('#emailsIn').text(d.emailsIn);
    d3.select('#emailsOut').text(d.emailsOut);
    d3.select('#im').text(d.im);
    d3.select('#phone').text(d.phone);
  }

  backgroundClicked(): void {
    let node = self.event.target as SVGElement;
    if (node.classList[0] !== 'relCirclesLayer') {
      d3.selectAll('.relCircles').attr('fill', '#58595b');
      d3.select('#detailsGroup').style('display', 'none');
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide more code about how your chart is rendered .

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below code to ngChanges() fixed the issue. Not sure whether it is an elegant answer:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    setTimeout(_ => this.redraw(), 10);
  }
```